# How would I use nested for loops to make a solid rectangle out of asterisks using java?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Box {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int length;
        int width;
        int rectangle;

        // input and output here

        System.out.print("Input the width of the box: ");
        width = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Input the length of the box: ");
        length = keyboard.nextInt();

        // use nested for loops here


    }

}
```

This is just what the base of my program is, I need a program that prints a solid rectangle out of asterisks using nested for loops.

Comment: show us what you have tried.

Comment: How do you print one asterisk? How do you print 1 line of `width` asterisks? How do you print `height` lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i< height; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<width; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This should do the trick, next time make sure to let us know what you have tried already. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class q1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int length;
        int width;
        int rectangle;

        // input and output here

        System.out.print("Input the width of the box: ");
        width = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Input the length of the box: ");
        length = keyboard.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i< length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<width; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}

/*
 * program output

Input the width of the box: 6
Input the length of the box: 7
*******
*******
*******
*******
*******
*******
*/
```

Comment: Change the width in the second for loop to length because previously it printed the width as the length.